# using filter in AngularJS table

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, filter

I'm creating a web app in `mvc with angularjs` in which i want to filter the data inside my table but I'm getting error while I debug my code.

This is what the error [is](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D)

> Error: $rootScope:infdig Infinite $digest Loop 10 $digest() iterations
>   reached. Aborting! Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []

I tried something like this

```
<tr ng-repeat="d in dataintbl| filter:search">
```

and I added another `tr`  in my `thead`

```
<td>
    <input type="text" ng-model="search.taskstartdate" placeholder="" class="erp-input" />
</td>
```

this is how my table looks

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr class="bg-primary">
        <th>Task Name</th>
        <th>Start Date</th>
        <th>End Date</th>
        <th>Priority</th>
        <th>Action</th>
        <th ng-hide="true">autoid</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" ng-model="search.taskstartdate" placeholder="" class="erp-input"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="d in dataintbl" ng-class="{'changecolor':(d.IsCompleted=='True')}">
        <td><a href="#" style="cursor:pointer;" ng-click="showdetails(d)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalc">{{d.taskname}}</a>
        </td>
        <td>{{d.taskstartdate}}</td>
        <td>{{d.taskenddate}}</td>
        <td ng-class="{'greenrow': (d.taskpriority == 'Low'), 'yellowrow': (d.taskpriority == 'Medium'), 'redrow': (d.taskpriority == 'High')}">
            {{d.taskpriority}}
        </td>
        <td>
            <span ng-class="{'hidespan':(d.IsCompleted=='False')}">Completed</span>
            <div ng-class="{'hidebutton':(d.IsCompleted=='True')}">

                <a href="#" ng-click="updatetask(d)" data-toggle="modal" title="EDIT TASK" data-target="#myModalb"
                   class="btn btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></a>
                <a href="#" ng-click="deleteuser(d)" title="DELETE TASK"
                   class="btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></a>
                <a href="#" ng-click="taskcompleted(d)" title="COMPLETE TASK"
                   class="btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I just want to understand, how can i give filters to the users?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle/plunker of your code

Comment: create a fiddle or plunker please

Comment: what the object that you are using ?? give some sample data ..  some of your data might be causing the problem

Comment: sir, can you provide your full code?

Comment: sir if you search data using input box then i think, you just need to change **ng-repeat="d in dataintbl"** to **ng-repeat="d in dataintbl | filter:search.taskstartdate"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change the following line

```
<tr ng-repeat="d in dataintbl" ng-class="{'changecolor':(d.IsCompleted=='True')}">
```

to something like this

```
<tr ng-repeat="d in dataintbl | filter:search.taskstartdate" ng-class="{'changecolor':(d.IsCompleted=='True')}">
```

and everything is looking fine